# Stepwise states implementation Tower of Hanoi Java

Tags: java

So I'm initially stuck on how to implement this stepwise state on my tower of hanoi code, I figured out how to output it like this

```
Move one disk from 0 to 2
Move one disk from 0 to 1
Move one disk from 2 to 1
Move one disk from 0 to 2
Move one disk from 1 to 0
Move one disk from 1 to 2
Move one disk from 0 to 2
```

but I'm stuck on how to implement a stepwise state of the tower like :

```
 Initially:
 peg0: 3 2 1
 peg1: 0 0 0
 peg2: 0 0 0
 Step 1: Move disk1 from peg0 to peg2 resulting
 peg0: 3 2 0
 peg1: 0 0 0
 peg2: 1 0 0
 Step 2: Move disk2 from peg0 to peg1 resulting
 peg0: 3 0 0
 peg1: 2 0 0
 peg2: 1 0 0
 Step 3: Move disk1 from peg2 to peg1 resulting
 peg0: 3 0 0
 peg1: 2 1 0
 peg2: 0 0 0
 Step 4: Move disk3 from peg0 to peg2 resulting
 peg0: 0 0 0
 peg1: 2 1 0
 peg2: 3 0 0  
 Step 5: Move disk1 from peg1 to peg0 resulting
 peg0: 1 0 0
 peg1: 2 0 0
 peg2: 3 0 0
 Step 6: Move disk2 from peg1 to peg2 resulting
 peg0: 1 0 0
 peg1: 0 0 0
 peg2: 3 2 0
 Step 7: Move disk1 from peg0 to peg2 resulting
 peg0: 0 0 0
 peg1: 0 0 0
 peg2: 3 2 1
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Main
{
    // Creates a TowersOfHanoi puzzle and solves it.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TowersOfHanoi towers = new TowersOfHanoi(3);
        towers.solve();
    }
}
```

TowersOfHanoi code

```
public class TowersOfHanoi
{
    private int totalDisks;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the puzzle with the specified number of disks.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    public TowersOfHanoi(int disks)
    {
        totalDisks = disks;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Performs the initial call to moveTower to solve the puzzle.
    // Moves the disks from tower 1 to tower 3 using tower 2.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    public void solve()
    {
        moveTower(totalDisks, 1, 3, 2);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Moves the specified number of disks from one tower to another
    // by moving a subtower of n-1 disks out of the way, moving one
    // disk, then moving the subtower back. Base case of 1 disk.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    private void moveTower(int numDisks, int start, int end, int temp)
    {
        if (numDisks == 1)
        {
            moveOneDisk(start, end);
        }
        else
        {
            moveTower(numDisks-1, start, temp, end);
            moveOneDisk(start, end);
            moveTower(numDisks-1, temp, end, start);
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Prints instructions to move one disk from the specified start
    // tower to the specified end tower.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    private void moveOneDisk(int start, int end)
    {
        System.out.println("Move one disk from " + start + " to " + end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a new field `private int step = 1;` to keep count of steps.
Store the pegs in a list `private List<LinkedList<Integer>> pegs= new ArrayList<>(3);`I have used LinkedList to represent the pegs so that the state of pegs can be printed easily.

Initialize the list of pegs in the constructor.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pegs.add(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Define a method to print the state of the towers.

```
private void printState() {
    int i = 0;
    for (LinkedList<Integer> peg : pegs) {
        System.out.print("peg" + i++ + ": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            try { 
                System.out.print(peg.get(j) + " ");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("0 ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Add disks on the peg0 in the method `void solve()` and print them. (It could also have been done in constructor but I think doing it in `solve()` is better). Pegs should be numbered from 0 to 2 while passing actual parameters for `start`, `end` and `temp`.

```
LinkedList<Integer> peg0 = pegs.get(0);
peg0.add(3);
peg0.add(2);
peg0.add(1);
System.out.println("Initially :");
printState();
moveTower(totalDisks, 0, 2, 1);
```

In `void moveOneDisk(int start, int end)`, print the step number  alongwith the message. Remove the last disk fron peg`start` and add it on peg`end`. Then call `printState()`.

```
System.out.println("Step " + step++ + ": Move one disk from " + start + " to " + end);
pegs.get(end).add(pegs.get(start).removeLast());
printState();
```